# Create a view with rounded corners (quarter circle)

Tags: ios, calayer, uibezierpath, cgpath, cashapelayer

I want to create a view as shown below

[image]

to achieve this I have tried the following:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myView.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
myView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

but it hasn't worked for me. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code :

```
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 200, 200)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myView.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(myView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(myView.frame))];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
myView.layer.mask = maskLayer;


CGRect frame = myView.frame;
CGRect remainder, slice;

CGRectDivide(frame, &slice, &remainder, CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2, CGRectMaxYEdge);

NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(remainder));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(slice));

CGRect remainder2, slice2;
CGRectDivide(remainder, &slice2, &remainder2, CGRectGetWidth(remainder)/2, CGRectMaxXEdge);

NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(remainder));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(remainder2));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(slice2));

myView.frame = remainder2;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

[image]

hopefully y answer is clear ..

Comment: Thank you !, it worked for me. I found something to achieve the same:

float width = 100;
    
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, width)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(width, width) radius:width startAngle:M_PI endAngle:(M_PI * 1.5f) clockwise:YES];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, width)];
    [path closePath];
    return path;

Comment: seems good.. I just follow your code to fix issue instead of introduce another solution ..  Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

it's work with me with this code :

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 200, 200)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myView.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
myView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is different from the answer. with the code attached in the question I can able to draw that but here I want to draw quarter circle.

Comment: sorry .. but what about using CGRectDivide ?  
check link : http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-divide-cgrect-using-cgrectdivide.html

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13, Swift 5 translation of the excellent answer by [Salah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274350/saleh-aldhobaie)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  halfCircle(.red)

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func halfCircle(_ color: UIColor) {
  let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
  myView.backgroundColor = color

  let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: myView.bounds.width, height: myView.bounds.height))
  let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds
  maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
  myView.layer.mask = maskLayer

  let frame = myView.bounds.divided(atDistance: 100.0, from: CGRectEdge.maxYEdge)

  debugPrint(frame)
  debugPrint(frame.remainder)
  debugPrint(frame.slice)

  let frame2 = frame.remainder.divided(atDistance: 100.0, from: CGRectEdge.maxXEdge)

  debugPrint(frame2)
  debugPrint(frame2.remainder)
  debugPrint(frame2.slice)

  myView.frame = frame2.remainder
  self.view.addSubview(myView)

  }
}
```